# @Api annotation description is not getting displayed

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have following in my code

```
@Path("/description")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api(value="description", description="Service description")
public class Service{
....
}
```

On swagger UI I am able to see

```
description: true
```

Instead of

```
description: Service description
```

Please help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. Please follow https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/578.